# Setting HttpOnly Classic ASP in IIS 5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-5, httponly, cookie-httponly

After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575794/setting-httponly-true-on-asp-1-1-session-id-cookie), I too need to set ASPSESSIONID[random-string-here] cookies to be HttpOnly for Classic ASP pages.  But, in IIS 5.

So, what are my options?  I'm not generating these cookies, they seem to be auto-generated.  Is there an IIS 5, global, web.config setting I could change?