# Make ASP.NET_SessionId cookie not httpOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

The cookie used for session in ASP.NET MVC is `httpOnly` (property set to true).

Is there a way to make it not httpOnly?

I want to be able to access this cookie from javascript.

Even if it is less secure than the "What if all the universe stands against me?!" default setting.

Comment: Where is the cookie created? Do you create it yourself, or is it generated by ASP.NET?

Comment: It's all MVC.Net handled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990686/setting-httponly-for-classic-asp-session-cookie?rq=1

Comment: Question becomes why do you need to do this? What is your logic behind it? For security reasons it is set to true for httpOnly by default.

Comment: Useful for training purposes - to demonstrate why the session cookie should always be httponly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *REALLY* need it you could try to add this to your Global.asax:

```
void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
   {
       foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
       {
           if (s == "ASP.NET_SessionId")
           {
               Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].HttpOnly = false;
           }
       }
   }    
}
```

Solution was taken from [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/955272/1177574.aspx#1177574).

Comment: Note: to test this one must not forget to erase the cookie from its browser beforehand. (Response.Cookies refers to newly added cookies only)

Answer (score 0):

I built a system that uses cookies to store search params across the site.
On the home page there are links and I wanted to use jQuery to save a cookie with the item id in it.

But on click the user is then sent to an advanced search page where they can use .net controls to modify the search. The cookies are saved again but they needed to be writable by the js on the home page when the user browsed back.

So I set HttpOnly like this:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(name)
{
   Value = val,
   HttpOnly = false // #DEV search cookies can be modified by JS
};
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```