# Set HttpOnly for classic ASP cookies

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

I amtrying to add HttpOnly to my Classic ASP cookies. I have tried all the solutions that I could find but seems like they are not working in my situation.
Here is the code that I have to set up cookies:

```
Sub StoreCookieValue(byVal strParameter, byVal strValue)
    Select Case UCase(strParameter)
    'Case "USERID":         Response.Cookies("SessionTestCom")("UserID") = strValue
    '                       gstrUserID = strValue


    Case "SESSID":          Response.Cookies("SessionTestCom")("SessID") = strValue 
                            gintSessionID = strValue

    Case "ACCESSNUMBER":    Response.Cookies("SessionTestCom")("AccessNumber") = strValue
                            gstrAccessNumber = strValue
    Case "USERIDKEY"   :    Response.Cookies("SessionTestCom")("UserIdKey") = strValue
                            gstrAccessNumber = strValue
    End Select

    Response.Cookies("SessionTestCom").Path = "/"
    Response.Cookies("SessionTestCom").Secure  = True
    Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", ""&CStr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE"))&";path=/;HttpOnly"&""

End Sub
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You're right. Have luck with your endeavors.

Comment: ... these comments make no sense. If y'all are gonna delete a conversation, please delete *all* of it. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting HTTPONLY for Classic Asp Session Cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990686/setting-httponly-for-classic-asp-session-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution that I applied and it works.

[Setting HTTPONLY for Classic Asp Session Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990686/setting-httponly-for-classic-asp-session-cookie)

I added the re-write rule to the iOS and it fixed it.